# Sort a list in a specific order comparer

Tags: c#, performance, icomparer

I have a list of strings and I need to write an `IComparer` implementation to sort them in a specific order.

My current implementation:

```
public enum TimeBucket
{
    [Description("0D")]
    ZeroDay,
    [Description("1D")]
    OneDay,
    [Description("1W")]
    OneWeek,
    [Description("2W")]
    TwoWeek,
    [Description("0M")]
    ZeroMonth,
    [Description("1M")]
    OneMonth
}

public class TimeBucketComparer : IComparer
{
    public static TimeBucketComparer Instance { get; } = new TimeBucketComparer();

    private TimeBucketComparer()
    {

    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        TimeBucket xvar = GetValue(string.Join("", x.ToString().Split(' ')));
        TimeBucket yvar = GetValue(string.Join("", y.ToString().Split(' ')));

        if (EqualityComparer<TimeBucket>.Default.Equals(xvar, default(TimeBucket)) &&
            EqualityComparer<TimeBucket>.Default.Equals(yvar, default(TimeBucket)))
            return String.CompareOrdinal(xvar.ToString(), yvar.ToString());

        if (EqualityComparer<TimeBucket>.Default.Equals(xvar, default(TimeBucket))) return -1;
        if (EqualityComparer<TimeBucket>.Default.Equals(yvar, default(TimeBucket))) return 1;

        return xvar.CompareTo(yvar);
    }

    public TimeBucket GetValue(string description) => EnumExtensions.GetValueFromDescription<TimeBucket>(description);


}
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        return ((DescriptionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(value.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Single(x => x.GetValue(null).Equals(value)),typeof(DescriptionAttribute)))?.Description ?? value.ToString();
    }

    public static T GetValueFromDescription<T>(string description)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        foreach (var field in type.GetFields())
        {
            var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
                typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                if (attribute.Description == description)
                    return (T)field.GetValue(null);
            }
            else
            {
                if (field.Name == description)
                    return (T)field.GetValue(null);
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("Not found.", "description");
        // or return default(T);
    }
}
```

My current implementation takes a lot of time because of the reflection involved. I used this way because of the need for a generic implementation.
Input has at least 40000 records of Timebuckets which need to be sorted. The sort algorithm is linq orderby which is generic and can't be modified. Hence, need to use a comparer.

I need to sort strings. Is there a better approach which doesn't use reflection?

Edit: In case it's not clear, my input is {"1M", "1D", "1W", "0D"} and the output i require is {"0D", "1D", "1W", "1M"}

Comment: Why not simply add explicit values to the `enum`?  `ZeroDay = 0, OneDay = 1, OneWeek = 7` and so on

Comment: I get the description data from the server. Not zeroday but 0D

Comment: So this comparer is for strings? I mean x and y are strings and not enums?

Comment: yes. I get timebucket as a string from server. i need to sort strings. writing =0 doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: Well, this has a big [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) written all over it. Please edit your question to include the underlying problem you try to solve.

Comment: i included an example as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't get your sorting logic but anyway - if you have perfomance problems because of reflection - just do reflection once and cache the results. For example:

```
public class TimeBucketComparer : IComparer, IComparer<string> {
    public static TimeBucketComparer Instance { get; } = new TimeBucketComparer();

    private static readonly Lazy<Dictionary<string, TimeBucket>> _values = new Lazy<Dictionary<string, TimeBucket>>(() => {
        // get all fields and store in dictionary, keyed by description attribute
        return typeof(TimeBucket)
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .ToDictionary(c => 
                c.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()?.Description ?? c.Name, 
                c => (TimeBucket) c.GetValue(null));
    });

    private TimeBucketComparer() {

    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y) {
        string xvar = string.Join("", x.ToString().Split(' '));
        string yvar = string.Join("", y.ToString().Split(' '));
        return Compare(xvar, yvar);   
    }

    public int Compare(string x, string y) {
        if (!_values.Value.ContainsKey(x))
        {
            // do something, invalid value
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(x));
        }
        if (!_values.Value.ContainsKey(y))
        {
            // do something, invalid value
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(y));
        }
        return _values.Value[x].CompareTo(_values.Value[y]);
    }
}
```

Comment: A nice XY solution to an XY problem... +1 :-)

Comment: the sorting logic is simple. i defined my custom order in an enum. my comparer takes the strings as input, converts them to enum compares the enums and returns the result.

Comment: @Skyuppercut well my sample code produces expected output for your test case (`{"1M", "1D", "1W", "0D"}` > `{"0D", "1D", "1W", "1M"}`) so I guess that's what you need. And I used the logic you describe.

Comment: Lazy loading and caching the values does help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Define your enum like :

```
public enum TimeBucket
    {
        [Description("0D")]
        ZeroDay = 0,
        [Description("1D")]
        OneDay = 1,
        [Description("1W")]
        OneWeek = 2,
        [Description("2W")]
        TwoWeek = 3,
        [Description("0M")]
        ZeroMonth = 4,
        [Description("1M")]
        OneMonth = 5
    }
```

Assuming this enum is property of some entity and you want to sort on the collection of that entity.

For example :

```
var sortedList = coll.OrderBy(x => (int) (x.TimeBucket)).ToList();
```

Comment: I can't change the content in the orderby code. it's generic and used by multiple other classes

Comment: you mean cannot change TimeBucket enum type ?

Comment: I get timebucket as a string from server. i need to sort strings. writing =0 doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: from the way you describe, it appears you need to have some mapping define at your end between these string and order. I mean have a `dictionary<string, int>` and use that for sorting. Let me know if thats the case ?

Comment: please check the question now. i added a sample example.

Comment: If `{"1M", "1D", "1W", "0D"}` is static data then i feel its much performant to create mapping with order and use that for sorting.

Comment: input comes from the server and is dynamic. i just provided an example

Comment: I get your point. Are you saying tomorrow you can even get "1Y" as well (OneYear) 
?

Comment: Yes. 1Y, 2Y etc

Comment: got it. so how you ensuring "1M"  > "1W" ? (oneMonth > OneWeek)